# How to generate a file from its MD5 sum

Tags: md5

The title says it all. From my understanding, every file has a unique MD5 checksum. Is it possible to reverse-engineer the file from its sum?

For example, let's just say a video's sum was 5. I know, but its just an example. Could you write a program where you enter 5 and it generates a video?

In other words, instead of generating a sum from a file, you get a file from a sum.

Comment: See the [Pigeonhole Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) for why this is not possible. Now, generating *some* particular data with the same hash, which is a different situation, is possible and the basis for various [Collision Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what Jim W said, any *hash function* is one-way, which means they're functions that don't need to be easily reversible — while some may have inverses, most do not.

MD5 is a *cryptographic* hash function, which means it's intentionally *designed* to be very difficult to reverse. MD5 in particular is relatively weak, there are vulnerabilities that make it easy to find *collisions* — two files with the same MD5 hash.

Since an MD5 hash is only 128 bits, there are 2^128 different possible MD5 hashes, and while that's a very large number, there are still many, many more files than that in the world (potentially an infinite number, in fact), so it is inevitable that *some* files will hash to the same value. This, as user2864740 pointed out in a comment, is known as the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

A *strong* cryptographic hash function — like SHA-256 — is one for which it's considered computationally infeasible to reliably find such collisions.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought it was mostly for error checking, like in file transfers.

Comment: @AnOptionalName Error checking is actually a great use for MD5, because that doesn't rely on its cryptographic strength. *Authenticity* checking, on the other hand — where you're trying to verify that the file you downloaded is from the person you think it's from — is *not* a good use for MD5 because of how easy it would be to create a different file with the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's one way - otherwise be great method of compression!

Comment: That was actually my plan. Lol, back do the drawing board. If some invents that u know there us a LOT of money to be made, right?